# easy way to show image next to textbox?

Tags: html, ajax

I trying to validate a form using ajax...I have got it to show either a cross or tick if the box passes valdation. This is done by showing or hiding a div tag, is there an easier way without me having to have a div tag for each cross & tick as this would use about 20 div tags.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS `:before` property to do this:

```
.tick:before {
    content:url(tick.gif);
}

.cross:before {
    content:url(cross.gif);
}
```

(you'll probably have to tweak the CSS a bit to get the image to display in the proper position)

Then in your javascript, just add the class `tick` or `cross` to each text box that you want to display an image next to.

Comment: Thanks, how would I do that in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Since your validation depends on javascript you could leave the divs out of the html initially and insert them after validating a field. Let's say your source is something like:

```
<p><input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" /></p>
```

Your script could be something like:

```
var emailField = document.getElementById('email');
if( isValid(emailField) ){
var tick = document.createElement('DIV');
tick.className = 'tick';
emailField.parentNode.appendChild(tick);
}else{
var cross= document.createElement('DIV');
cross.className = 'cross';
emailField.parentNode.appendChild(cross);
}
```

You add the classes '.tick' and '.cross' to your css and apply background images. Of course, you need some checking if the element was already inserted by a previous validation. This is just a simple example.

This way you don't need the extra divs initially.